# how to take printout without URL of the site using html

Tags: javascript, html

I give code for taking **printout** of the page. But the page is coming along with the **URL**. So while taking **printout** that **URL** is also showing in page..

**My Javascript Code**

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    function PrintPanel() {
        var panel = document.getElementById("pnlContents");
        var printWindow = window.open('', '', 'height=400,width=800');
        printWindow.document.write('<html><head><title>DIV Contents</title>');
        printWindow.document.write('</head><body >');
        printWindow.document.write(panel.innerHTML);
        printWindow.document.write('</body></html>');
        printWindow.document.close();
        setTimeout(function () {
            printWindow.print();
        }, 500);
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

My html submit button is looking like,

```
<input type="button" id="btnPrint" value="print" onclick="return PrintPanel();" style="color:#FFFFFF; background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #7C8399;border-color: #999999 -moz-use-text-color #CCCCCC #999999;" />
```

Also i have attached the screenshot.. Let me know is it possible or not?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can by adding the option `location=no` to your window but this will not work on all browser. For security reasons you can't hide the address bar on many recent browser.

```
function PrintPanel() {
    var panel = document.getElementById("pnlContents");
    var printWindow = window.open('', '', 'height=400,width=800,location=0');
    printWindow.document.write('<html><head><title>DIV Contents</title>');
    printWindow.document.write('</head><body >');
    printWindow.document.write(panel.innerHTML);
    printWindow.document.write('</body></html>');
    printWindow.document.close();
    setTimeout(function () {
        printWindow.print();
    }, 500);
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It will be better if you convert into `pdf` and then open that file and print.

An online application which is working on the above concept is `Google Docs`. So, I would like you to go with this method. `Google Docs` prints without the `header` and `footer`.

Comment: To convert to `pdf` follow the answer from this question http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/152470/how-to-convert-an-html-page-to-pdf-using-javascript